# Page counter for css elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have a simple script that navigates to the following pages highlighted in yellow and green below.

My question is, how do I create a page counter so I know where the job is at for this?

Ideally it would read:

```
Page 5
Page 4 #For each of the loop
```

The following tends to work, though I am having issues with the following:

```
elements = [x.get_text("*") for x in
        wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//div[div/div/text()="Main Lists"]//div[starts-with(@class, "sm-CouponLink_Label") and normalize-space()]')))]
```

Full code:

```
import collections
from random import shuffle

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()


driver.get('https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AS/B1/')
driver.get('https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AS/B1/')



def page_counter():
    for x in range(1000):
        yield x


clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//div[div/div/text()="Main Lists"]//div[starts-with(@class, "sm-CouponLink_Label") and normalize-space()])')))
options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[div/div/text()="Main Lists"]//div[starts-with(@class, "sm-CouponLink_Label") and normalize-space()]')

indexes = [index for index in range(len(options))]
shuffle(indexes)
for index in indexes:


    count = page_counter()
    driver.get('https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AS/B1/')
    elements = [x.get_text("*") for x in
            wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//div[div/div/text()="Main Lists"]//div[starts-with(@class, "sm-CouponLink_Label") and normalize-space()]')))]


       #elements = [x.get_attribute("href") for x in
       # driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[div/div/text()="Main Lists"]//div[starts-with(@class, "sm-CouponLink_Label") and normalize-space()]')))]

    clickMe.click()
    shuffle(elements)

    links = dict((next(count) + 1, e) for e in elements)

desc_links = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(links.items(), reverse=True))
for key, value in desc_links.items():
    try:
        driver.get(value)
        print('Page ' + str(key))
    except TimeoutException as ex:
        pass
```

Error:

```
line 36, in <module>
    wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//div[div/div/text()="Main Lists"]//div[starts-with(@class, "sm-CouponLink_Label") and normalize-space()]')))]
  File "C:\Users\Django\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

[image]

Comment: `wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator))` intend to return you WebElement which is not iterable. try `wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(locator))` instead. Also add definition of `get_text()` function

Comment: @Andersson What would the get_text look like in this case, I'm getting same errors when  I add css

Comment: Do you ask me about `get_text()`? I don't know how should it look like - it's your code, your function :) *...when I add css...* Add to what? Describe the issue in more details and provide with exact error log

Comment: @Andersson I've posted examples.  Here: https://pastebin.com/fyXjkLi0 /  I've generally only dealt with HREF, so I'm a bit confused on how I go about doing countdown for clicking non href.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the listings under the main list not being hrefs, you cannot have the driver open all the listings by using driver.get() (at least to my knowledge), you'd have to click all the listings one by one and get the information.

see if this code helps to get started, replace the time.sleep with better wait logic

```
driver.get('https://www.bet365.com.au/#/AS/B1/')

driver.find_element_by_id('TopPromotionBetNow').click()

time.sleep(10)
classifications = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('wn-Classification')
for classification in classifications:
    if classification.text == 'Soccer':
        classification.click()
        break

time.sleep(10)
markets = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sm-Market')
for market in markets:
    group_name = market.find_element_by_class_name('sm-Market_GroupName')
    if group_name.text == 'Main Lists':
        coupon_lables = [x for x in market.find_elements_by_class_name('sm-
                         CouponLink_Label')]
    break

for label in coupon_lables:
    print('executing:' + label.text)
    label.click()

    # do your stuff 
    # find the back button (<) on the web page, click on it
    # go back to select the next label
```

**update**

```
coupon_lables = [x.text for x in market.find_elements_by_class_name('sm-CouponLink_Label')]

for label in coupon_lables:
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//div[contains(text(), "' + label + '")]').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('cl-BreadcrumbTrail_BackButton').click()
```

Comment: I am getting: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document - https://pastebin.com/LHna0MCr

Comment: which line is throwing that error? I'm not able to replicate as its working on my systsm

Comment: Can you update it with: wait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ("wn-Classification")))) or equivalent.  time.sleep does not seem to be working.

Comment: change to By.CLASS_NAME, the locator is a class name, It worked for me

Comment: Can you update your example, I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I have updated the code. I believe all the elements under main list are getting rewritten in the dom when you navigate away and go back to click them. so instead of storing elements in coupon_lables, I'm storing the text and while going through all the labels, I'm using the text to locate the element. This way the code will search for an element rather than try to use the stored one. Replace the time.sleep with your wait. Having said that, this may not be a good solution, given if any text from main lists matches under different category

Comment: How do I print the count down? print('executing:' + label) gives: executing:Thursday's Matches.  This prints same page: https://pastebin.com/LzaQ2uPM

Comment: Still not counting down for me.  Feel free to update your answer and post here so I can accept your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854129/creating-a-page-count-down-in-python-selenium

Comment: Still not counting down.  Alright, I'm going to take a look at this from the ground up as I don't think this approach works.

Comment: I think so too, the approach worked when you had links to navigate. But on this website, all the content are exposed via tags which are not links. You need to come up with a approach that'd work for any website. Let me know if you need any help